# Multiple video player and fullscreen canvas with two videos

Tags: html, video, video-processing

How can I render two videos in fullscreen view on just one canvas at the same time?

I'm trying to create a videoplayer that can play **two videos at once** using just one video control interface. I tried out different approaches and would be thankful for some general thoughts on how to start realizing the player. I am also looking for a solution for **fullscreen** view of both videos and a mobile view.

Thanks a lot for your input!

I'm trying to create something like this example: (multiple video player wireframe):

[image]

Comment: _"I tried out different approaches"_ any more (brief) info about this, so people aren't just typing things you've already tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem is about video editing not **programming** (therefore off-topic for this specific forum)

Comment: @VC.One thanks for your reply I'll add a summary of my approaches to the question. The videoplayer is supposed to work in HTML so it's not a video editing question.

Comment: I don't know how much progress you've made since the edit. I've gone into teacher mode and shown an example code. Just research tutorials, try something, and check against the shown working example.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding New Edit:**

> *"How can I render two videos in fullscreen view on just one canvas at the same time?"*

Here is good example of showing two videos side by side. You'll have to tweak things (display widths & heights) to see how it all works. The code assumes the two videos are both **width 640** and have max **height 480** (is okay if smaller height). Hence:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="600"></canvas>
```

Since assuming `width 640 x 2 videos = 1280;`

If checked in fullsceen mode then `screen.width` reports your display's **full screen width** at that time. You'll have to double-check the aspect-ratio maths if working with various resolutions.

Look at `function on_fullscreen_change()` and the line *`my_canvas.width = screen.width / aspectRatio;`* for an idea on calculating asect ration. That one is fined tuned for two 640 videos so it fits 1280 pixels int my TV screen's own 1600 pixel width (non-HDMI, using VGA cable).

The code is generally short & simple. Here it looks long because it takes care of some extra things (*eg:* aspect ratio):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="600"></canvas>

<br>

<video id="myVid1" width="0" height="0" controls>
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="myVid2" width="0" height="0" controls>
<source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>


<script>

//# get access to Canvas as "my_canvas"
var my_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var my_ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//# starting video width/height values (don't need to be correct)
var vid_A_Width = 0; var vid_A_Height = 0;
var vid_B_Width = 0; var vid_B_Height = 0;

//# ASPECT RATIO (...is calculated further below)
//# new height = (original height / original width) x new width;
var aspectRatio = 0; //(myVid1.videoWidth / myVid1.videoheight).toFixed(3);

myVid1.onloadedmetadata = function() 
{
    //# set width & height according to video file's own metadata

    vid_A_Width = myVid1.videoWidth; vid_A_Height = myVid1.videoHeight;

    myVid2.onloadedmetadata = function() 
    {
        vid_B_Width = myVid2.videoWidth; vid_B_Height = myVid2.videoHeight;
        aspectRatio = (canvas.width / canvas.height);
        //alert( "aspectRatio : " + aspectRatio);
    }
}   

//# listen for full-screen and handle via functions
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', on_fullscreen_change); //if firefox
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', on_fullscreen_change); //if Chrome/Edge/Safari
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

//# handle play / pause
function play_pause() 
{
    if (myVid1.paused == true) 
    { 
        myVid1.play(); myVid2.play(); canvas_DrawUpdate();

        //# try available fullscreen modes using "OR" || operator
        my_canvas.requestAnimationFrame(canvas_DrawUpdate)
        //|| mozRequestAnimationFrame (canvas_DrawUpdate)
        //|| webkitRequestAnimationFrame (canvas_DrawUpdate)
        //|| msRequestAnimationFrame (canvas_DrawUpdate)
    }
    else 
    { 
        //myVid1.pause(); myVid2.pause();

        my_canvas.cancelAnimationFrame(canvas_DrawUpdate)
        //|| mozCancelAnimationFrame(canvas_DrawUpdate)
        //|| webkitRequestAnimationFrame (canvas_DrawUpdate)
    }
}

//# handle frame updating within Canvas pixels
function canvas_DrawUpdate()
{
    my_ctx.drawImage(myVid1,0,0,640,480); //draw video A
    my_ctx.drawImage(myVid2,641,0,640,480); //draw video B

    //# feedback loop...
    requestAnimationFrame(canvas_DrawUpdate); //wait for browser to present another animation frame.       
}

//# set Canvas "my_canvas" to full screen
function canvas_Fullscreen()
{
    if ( my_canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen ) { my_canvas.webkitRequestFullScreen(); }
    else { my_canvas.mozRequestFullScreen(); }            
}

//# set width & height according to video file's own metadata
function on_fullscreen_change() 
{
    if(document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen) 
    {
        vid_A_Width = screen.width; vid_A_Height = screen.height;
        aspectRatio = (screen.width / myVid1.videoWidth) / 2;

        //# use "screen.width divide by aspect ratio" (eg: my_canvas.width = screen.width / 1.333;
        my_canvas.width = screen.width / aspectRatio; //can try: 1.333;
    }
    else 
    {
        my_canvas.width = screen.width;
        //my_canvas.height = ??;
    }
}

</script>



<br><br>

<button onclick="play_pause()"> PLAY/PAUSE </button>

<button onclick="canvas_Fullscreen()"> FULL-SCREEN </button>

</html>
```

---

**Older Answer...**

**(1)**

> *"I'm trying to create a videoplayer that can play two videos at once..."*

Use Javascript to control the playing of two videos at once. I'll update this part if you show/tell how you're stuck with whatever you've tried.

**(2)**:

> *"Using just one video control interface... I am also looking to fullscreen view both videos"*

For that you'll have to combine both videos (side by side) into one final MP4 video file. This way you can will control playback and full-screen both "views".

[image]

This can be done with your favourite video editor tool or you can use FFmpeg (free).

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[myvid]" -map [myvid] -an test_output.mp4
```

Comment: My first approach was building a video player from scratch with this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player I managed to control both videos with the same controls but failed to show both of them in fullscreen mode. It's important that the videos can have two different sources and are not just merged together with a video editor. Also I was hoping to find a player that can achieve the described problem so I don't have to code everything myself and as a result will have lots of browser compatibility problems.

Comment: I also tried to work with video.js but here my problem was that I wasn't able to separate the control elements from the video in order to use it for both videos.

Comment: You'll have to draw both videos to a canvas and then fullscreen the canvas itself.

Comment: PS: If you try something with canvas and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52793471/edit) I'll try test / fix it for you.

Comment: Pause doesn't seem to work in the code you wrote...

Comment: @dakini just remove the `//` in the line `//myVid1.pause(); myVid2.pause();`.